# My charts in Metapost are at different scales. How I can improve it?

Tags: metapost, size, charts

I have a little problem with my **Metapost** **graphics**. My charts are at different **scales**.

I will attach an example of how it looks on the page.

On **the second graph**, you can clearly see **its name** and **the os arrow**.

However, **on the first graph**, as you can see, **the os arrow and graphic name are very-very small**.

I also add *.mp* files.
Maybe I have to change **t**? What can you advice to me? :)

[image: My code]

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{document}
```

**File1.mp:**

```
prologues:=3;
verbatimtex
%&latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[estonian]{babel}
\begin{document}
etex;
beginfig(1);

numeric u;
u := 1cm;

path kover;
kover:=(0,0)
for t:=0.01 step 0.1 until 6.75:     
  ..((3*t)*(cosd (360*t/3.14))*u, (3*t)*(sind (360*t/3.14))*u)

endfor;
draw kover;
drawarrow (0,0)--(8*3.14*u,0);
draw (0,0)--(10*(3.14/2)*u, 10*(3.14/2)*u);
label.top(btex $\rho = 3\varphi$ etex, ((-3*3.14)*u, (7*3.14/2)*u));

endfig;
end
```

**File2.mp:**

```
prologues:=3;
verbatimtex
%&latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[estonian]{babel}
\begin{document}
etex;
beginfig(2);

numeric u;
u := 1cm;

path kover;
kover:=(0,0)
for t:=0.01 step 0.01 until 6.31:     
  ..((t/2)*(cosd (360*t/3.14))*u, (t/2)*(sind (360*t/3.14))*u)

endfor;
draw kover;

path koverm;
koverm:=(0,0)
for t:=0.01 step 0.01 until 4.1:     
  ..((-t/2)*(cosd (360*t/3.14))*u, (t/2)*(sind (360*t/3.14))*u)
endfor;
draw koverm dashed evenly;
drawarrow (0,0)--(1.2*3.14*u,0);
label.top(btex $x$ etex, (1.2*3.14*u, 0));
label.top(btex $\rho = \frac{\varphi}{2}$ etex, ((3.14/1.5)*u, (3.14/4)*u));
endfig;
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code for the figure 1.

```
beginfig(1);    
numeric u;
u := 1cm;

path kover;
kover:=(0,0)
for t:=0.01 step 0.01 until 6.75:     
..((t/2)*(cosd (360*t/3.14))*u, (t/2)*(sind (360*t/3.14))*u)    
endfor;
draw kover; 

drawarrow (0,0)--(1.2*3.14*u,0);
draw (0,0)--(4*(3.14/5)*u, 5*(3.14/5)*u);
label.top(btex $x$ etex, (1.2*3.14*u, 0));
label.top(btex $\rho = 3\varphi$ etex, ((3.14/1.5)*u, (3.14/4)*u));

endfig;
```

[image: a]

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `width=0.45\textwidth` as this will use arbitrary scale factors. Use  `scale=0.2` or whatever scale you need, using the same scale for each. You should also remove the `\vspace` between the two images, as it can not add vertical space in that positon.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you want the picture to be about the same size. Since you do rho=3phi and rho=phi/2, and use approximately the same domain for phi, it might be meaningful to use different scales. Below I show the result I get with `u:=0.2cm` and `u:=1.2cm`.

Also, I include the code directly in my tex file (I use ConTeXt, so that looks a bit different). You can do something similar in LaTeX, for example by using the [luamplib](https://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/macros/luatex/generic/luamplib/luamplib.pdf) package. Another good thing with this is that you can get the same font as you use in your document, and with no scaling.

```
\starttext

\startplacefloat[figure]
\startcombination[nx=2,ny=1]
{\startMPcode

numeric u;
u := .2cm;

path kover;
kover:=(0,0)
for t:=0.01 step 0.1 until 6.75:     
  ..((3*t)*(cosd (360*t/3.14))*u, (3*t)*(sind (360*t/3.14))*u)
endfor ;
draw kover;
drawarrow (0,0)--(8*3.14*u,0);
draw (0,0)--(10*(3.14/2)*u, 10*(3.14/2)*u);
label.top(btex $\rho = 3\varphi$ etex, ((-3*3.14)*u, (7*3.14/2)*u));

\stopMPcode}{(a)}
{\startMPcode
numeric u;
u := 1.2cm;

path kover;
kover:=(0,0)
for t:=0.01 step 0.01 until 6.31:     
  ..((t/2)*(cosd (360*t/3.14))*u, (t/2)*(sind (360*t/3.14))*u)
endfor ;
draw kover;

path koverm;
koverm:=(0,0)
for t:=0.01 step 0.01 until 4.1:     
  ..((-t/2)*(cosd (360*t/3.14))*u, (t/2)*(sind (360*t/3.14))*u)
endfor ;
draw koverm dashed evenly;
drawarrow (0,0)--(1.2*3.14*u,0);
label.top(btex $x$ etex, (1.2*3.14*u, 0));
label.top(btex $\rho = \frac{\varphi}{2}$ etex, ((3.14/1.5)*u, (3.14/4)*u));
\stopMPcode}{(b)}
\stopcombination
\stopplacefloat

\stoptext
```

Compiled with `context`, this gives

[image: spirals]

Happy MetaPosting!